# AngularJS Formly - Setting ID/Name of fields

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-formly

I originally asked this question as a comment in another formly releated question here on SO.  I figured that this really should be its own question...

I have a repeating section of fields very similar to the following example: http://angular-formly.com/#/example/advanced/repeating-section

Looking at the repeater example, all of the fields have the same model name/id just in a different element of the investments array. Is it possible to give these fields a unique name/id? (investmentName_1, investimentName_2, etc) My validation is flagging the same field among all of the repeated sections whenever one of them fails validation. I have a feeling it is because they all have the same model name/id and thus my validation code is flagging all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify an `id` property on your field configuration. I updated the example to add a random ID property to the fields. Hopefully this fixes your issue.

Comment: Awesome.  This is exactly what I needed.  I updated the name, too.  Thanks man.

Comment: You're welcome! Note, the `name` will be set as the `id` unless a `name` is specified.